# In what fan-fiction story does the Doctor team up with the Enterprise crew against the Daleks and Klingons?

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, doctor-who, fan-fiction

As far as I can remember, the plot summary was something like this: "Due to <some sort of [negative space wedgie](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NegativeSpaceWedgie)>, the Daleks have been able to invade the Star Trek universe. They have teamed up with the Klingons, and are in the process of destroying everything in their path. In order to stop them, the Doctor and the crew of the Enterprise have teamed up."

I am quite sure that it isn't [the comic book.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation/Doctor_Who:_Assimilation2) *Assimilation<sup>2</sup>* is very good (I've read it), but I specifically remember that the story I am trying to identify is a book.

If it helps, I think it is set during the ToS era of Star Trek, although I'm unsure about when it was written.

Comment: Could this be a fan-fic?  I'm pretty sure there was never an officially sanctioned TOS/Who crossover.

Comment: @DavidW Assimilation2 was the only officially sanctioned Star Trek/Dr Who crossover, although it involved the Cybermen teaming up with the Borg, appearances by the Fourth Doctor and TOS-era crew, and the Eleventh Doctor and the TNG crew

Comment: I cannot find any mention of a plot line like this with the Daleks and the Klingons (in fact when I google "daleks try to invade star trek universe and team up with Klingons" the first hit is this post)

Comment: @DavidW Yes. I believe it is a fanfic.

Comment: Daleks have no honour.

Comment: @Paul They have no need for honour.